# How to get pixels filled by fillText() on HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, pixel

I am trying to find a way to get the pixels filled by fillText() method for 'one character' placed on HTML Canvas at random (x,y) location. This canvas may have other content already filled. I could not come up with a solution that works in various scenarios (character written on empty canvas, character written in empty location in otherwise filled canvas, canvas with background image, etc.) One method I could think of was to get `canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)` before and after fillText() and find changed pixels, but many conditions (font and fillStyle, gradients, aliasing, background image, character overlapping other content, etc.) throw this method off. Is there any easier and straight forward way to get the pixels filled by fillText() method? I am guessing experts here would know how to get the info that is already known to fillText() and canvas, without doing a detective job in the dirty pixels. Please help.

Comment: Nope, no other way than draw it first then get the changed pixels data through getImageData. You could make it faster by using an empty canvas though, so you just need to check for alpha channel > 0.

Comment: @Kaiido, Thank you for that confirmation. This is a very cumbersome, slow, and error prone method. If the character is written on top of another with same characteristics, detecting change is troublesome. I wonder why fillText() doesn't have a way to return what it changed in canvas and why canvas doesn't have a way to provide the changes made after a call, instead of us doing the detective work without much knowledge about the landscape of pixels.